# jQuery how to rapidly change color on divs with click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, colors

I made some litle jQuery little script who change color on click with animation({"height":"0px"},1000). But it works for only for one click. How i can make on every click to change colour?

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:red;
}

#div2 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:blue;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div1').click(function (){
                $('#div2').animate({"height":"0px"});
              $('#div1').css({"height":"200px"});
           });
        });
```

**HERE** : you can test this little script http://jsfiddle.net/phmxbf5k/

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with second click?
I mean, you want this div to become blue again after animation?

Comment: to change back color to blue (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmf9kbs2/2/

I've added an if-clause to the function, checking wich div is at full size now to determine which one should be animated.
After that, I let them switch places to make the "go-round" possible:

```
function toggleAnimation() {
    var active_div, hidden_div;
    if ( $('#div1').css("height") == "200px" ) {
    active_div = "#div1"; hidden_div = "#div2"; }
    else {active_div = "#div2"; hidden_div = "#div1";}

    $(active_div).animate({"height":"0px"});
    $(hidden_div).css({"height":"200px"}); 
    $(active_div).insertAfter(hidden_div);

};


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrap').click(function(){
        if ( ($("#div1, #div2").is(':animated'))==false ) {
        toggleAnimation()
        }
    })
});
```

had to alter the HTML too:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

...and added some CSS:

```
.wrap {position:relative;}
.wrap div {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: But why after fast clicking box disappears?

Comment: becuase you were clicking before animation was finished! I've added a check, if one of this div's is animating: http://jsfiddle.net/gmf9kbs2/2/

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to animate like this (in this script) http://www.editoskastingas.lt/en?

Comment: the JS for the function on the site you posted has about 600 lines :) sure it's possible, but would need a lot of forking - you'd have to check, which parent was clicked, and animate the (multiple) children accordingly. I assume it would cost me the whole afternoon to do this (bug-free), so I can't do that one for free, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code and you don't have to use two Divs to do so, you can just do like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bool = true;
  $('#div1').click(function() {
    if (bool == true) {
      $('#div1').css({
        "background": "blue"
      });
      bool = false;
    } else {
      $('#div1').css({
        "background": "red"
      });
      bool = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Div Content
</div>
```

Keep the same CSS for div1, and it'll give you the wanted animation.

Answer (score 0):

I added some CSS and some other jquery to the divs:

**Jquery:**

```
$('#div').click(function (){
    var div1Class = $('#div div').attr('id');
    if(div1Class == 'div1'){
        $('#div div').animate().attr('id', 'div2');
    }
    else{
        $('#div div').attr('id', 'div1');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
background:red;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
#div2 {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:blue;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Example here: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/phmxbf5k/60/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way ----

http://jsfiddle.net/phmxbf5k/68/

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('#div1').click(function (){  
        $('#div2').toggleClass("changeBackground");
    });
});

.changeBackground{
   background: blue;
}
```